# Saving file using url, without opening new tab

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

In my project I use **file-saver** to download files.
When the file is in blob format, downloading acts as expected (i.e. starts downloading file, without opening new tab), however if I use URL as a parameter, new tab with the file is opened and downloading just doesn't start.

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver'

const saveFile = async (file) => {
  try {
    saveAs(file.url, file.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Is there any way to download file by providing URL, without opening new tab? If not, how can I make this download start in this new tab?
I can't use blob in this situation.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73652169/16550663) might be relevant